# How do i use get_reaction_users?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

```
if message.content.startswith('!stopafk'):
        await client.send_message(botspam,"y")
        LHss = discord.Reaction("LH:461777566408376321")
        users = await client.get_reaction_users(LHss,limit=100)
```

I have this code and i have no idea how to make it work, i have tried everything and nothing i have found has worked or helped 
i know i'm probably just being stupid but it says that the `"LH....`" is 2 arguments but it just isn't.
I have replaced the emote with `<Emote:ID>`, `<:Emote:ID>`,`<:Emote:#ID#>`,`<Emote#ID#>`literally everything and i don't know what i'm meant to do.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Are you trying to get the users who have reacted to something?  I don't think there's a way to get a reaction from an `id`.  You'll instead have to get the message and from there use `Message.reactions` to get the reaction.

Answer (score 2):

This took me longer than I'm willing to admit to finding out.
Here is an example of what I used in my code :)

```
@client.command(pass_context = True)
async def test(ctx):

    msg = await client.say('TEST')
    await client.add_reaction(msg, "✅")
    await asyncio.sleep(5)

    cache_msg = discord.utils.get(client.messages, id = msg.id)
    for reactor in cache_msg.reactions:
        reactors = await client.get_reaction_users(reactor)

        #from here you can do whatever you need with the member objects
        for member in reactors:
            await client.say(member.name)
```